# Derivative of the exponential of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What's the general expression of $\dfrac{d ^n e^{f(x)}}{d  x^n}$ in term of derivative $\dfrac{d f(x)}{d x}$, $\dfrac{d ^2e^{f(x)}}{d x^2}$,$\dfrac{d ^3e^{f(x)}}{d x^3},\dots$?

Actually I wonder whether there is a special expression for the series of coefficients for different integers $n$? Some of the series: $(1),(1,1),(1,3,1),(1,6,4,3,1),(1,10,10,5,15,10,1)\dots$

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula can help you.

Comment: Why are you using partial derivative notation? Is your function a function of several variables, or just one?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin sorry for my misleading expression;i've already edited my question. Here i only consider the one variable case.( the original expression is copied from Mathematica, so it is in term of partial derivative)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula

This is stated in the language of power series.  The coefficients in the power series are the derivatives evalutated at $0$.  You can do this at points other than $0$ by looking at powers of $x-x_0$ rather than powers of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), we can write 
$$\frac{d^ne^{f(x)}}{dx^n}=e^{f(x)}\sum_{k=0}^nB_{n,k}(f'(x),\dots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x)),$$
where $B_{n,k}$ is [Bell's polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/) (under the section "Exp from function"), we have the formula

$$\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}\exp(g(z))=\exp(g(z))\sum_{m=0}^k\frac1{m!}\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j \binom{m}{j} g(z)^j\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}g(z)^{m-j}$$